# MySQL and Python: commits from one thread not visible to another thread, but visible from MySQL Workbench

Tags: python, mysql

I have two Python threads accessing the same MySQL database, each with its own connection and cursor object. One thread inserts a record into a table. As I would expect, from MySQL Workbench, I don't see the table grow in length until the writing thread does a commit, then I see the change. The problem is, my other thread doesn't see the change: it sees the old state of the table, as if the commit never happened. When I restart the application, the length of the table does get read correctly, but remains stuck there for all eternity, no matter how many records the writing thread appends and commits. I feel like I'm missing something really obvious here.

To read the length of the table, I've tried:
select count(*) from mystupidtable
select count(id) from mystupidtable
and even:
select id from mystupidtable

All these attempts return the old state of the table, as though the commit never happened.

Comment: Maybe you could try to create a new connection in another thread to see what happen?

Comment: Maybe it's a race condition. Your reader finishes before your writer. You say that if you restart the reader, it gets the new state. Without any code it's hard to say what's wrong, but it seems like you're accidentally keeping old state, or not updating it properly.

Comment: No, it can't be a race condition because the reader updates the table length reading every 10 seconds, and it never corrects itself. I'm sure I'm not updating something or other properly. I may have to distill this into a minimal test case so I have an example of the problem without all the noise.

Comment: Are the connections caching the table?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the 2nd thread is running off a snapshot of the database from when it implicitly opened a transaction. (Which I *think* cursors do.) If so, committing the cursor on the 2nd thread should allow it to see the new data.

See
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-consistent-read.html
and the REPEATABLE READ level.

Comment: I think you're right about the snapshot, although I tried committing and it didn't change anything. I finally cured the headache by cutting off the head: the write thread queries the table length and puts it into a queue. The GUI thread reads this queue to get the info. That seems to work.